# Unable to import Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I am running a simple java program and `import java.util.Hashtable<Integer, String>;` will not compile. The command line says:

```
practice1.java:1: error: ';' expected
import java.util.Hashtable<Integer, String>;
                          ^
1 error
```

But this doesn't make any sense.

**Edit:**

I tried `import java.util.Hashtable;`, but it gave me an error:

> Note: practice1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: Post the code so that people can help you and also provide how are you running, are you running using any IDE ?

Comment: Even when you import a generified type like `Map` or `Set`, your `import` statement should only use their *class* names, which are `java.util.Map` and `java.util.Set` respectively. Their full specified type name is not a thing you should write while importing them.

Comment: I don't use an IDE, just Atom and command line to run it. It's not necessary to post all the code, the issue is only with importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```java
import java.util.Hashtable;
```

But you really want to use `Map` and probably `HashMap` instead.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// ...

Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Note that if synchronisation is an issue, you need to use ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: I see, thank you. The reason I practice Hashtable is because of interviews (frequently asked).

Comment: Tell the interviewer that `Hashtable` is ancient and not used by anybody for years if not decades. Don't join a company that used this class.

Comment: @David Interviewers are likely asking about the **concept** hashtable, not about the specific `java.util.Hashtable` which was pretty much superseded by `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap` years ago.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I concluded. Thank you for mentioning